# UIView wont appear

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I have a function in my viewController that lays out my views using SnapKit. The funcion looks like this

```
 @objc func setupView(){
        //will add the scroll view to the subview

            view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageContainer)
    scrollView.addSubview(eventInfoVIew)
   // scrollView.addSubview(currentEventImage)

    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .green
    eventInfoVIew.backgroundColor = .red
    imageContainer.backgroundColor = .blue

    scrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    imageContainer.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 200)
    eventInfoVIew.anchor(top: imageContainer.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: scrollView.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)


    }




override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = view.safeAreaInsets
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: 0)
    }
```

However when I run the app one of the views isn't there and it makes no sense because to the best of my knowledge I laid out the constraints properly. The eventInfoView is the one giving me problems.

Sorry forgot to add image of current screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you try debugging with the view inspector? What happens with your views? A screenshot of the view hierarchy would help a lot.

Without this, my hunch is that you are not using enough constraints and therefore your layout is ambiguous. Don't forget that `UIScrollView` requires **6 constraints** to layout properly instead of 4.

---

Edit: If you want to check if the scrollView is the issue, try adding this code inside

```
scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.edges.equalTo(view)
    make.width.height.equalTo(view)   
}
```

Comment: the scroll view is the green view

Comment: the eventInfoVIew seems to not even be there

Comment: Yes the scrollView probably has the correct `frame` but its `contentView` might not have the correct size. You need two extra constraints for that.

Comment: I checked the view hiearchy

Comment: Is the `eventInfoView` inside the `scrollView` at least? In the tree